# console log shows the entire file instead of data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
<script>
var h = $(window).height();
alert (h); // works fine - shows 580
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {h : h},
    success:(function(data){
        console.log( data );
    })
});
</script>
```

As a result console shows the entire index.php file, instead of `h` data (580) !?

Comment: use `console.log( data[h] )`;

Comment: your url file(index.php) is same. change it.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, in that case there is no any data in console !

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here. You're getting the same file and trying to log out the file. Data will be populated with the same page, which makes sense -- but it doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you use in the line `console.log( data );` is the `data` you declare in the line `success:(function(data){` which is the body of the HTTP response you get from requesting `index.php`.

It has nothing to do with the data property you use in the line `data: {h : h},` or the variable `h`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

**At the top of your index.php file add this codes**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['h'])){
    echo $_POST['h'];
    die();
}
?>
```

**then**

```
<script>
var h = $(window).height();
alert (h); // works fine - shows 580
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {h : h},
    success:(function(data){
       console.log( data );
    })
});
</script>
```